# how to display the latest captured video thumbnail beside my capture button in camera app ios

Tags: ios6, ios6.1, video-thumbnails, ios-camera

I am building a camera based app. In this app I am able to display the latest captured image thumbnail beside the capture button. Now how to do the same with the video thumbnail, I mean how to display the latest captured video thumbnail beside my capture button in camera ios. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are enumerating the assets using an enumeration block - 
For the assets that you are enumerating, check the property key `ALAssetPropertyType` in your enumeration block like this:

```
if([asset valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){

    CGImageRef thumbnailVidoeImageRef = [asset thumbnail];
    // Do what you want with this CGImageRef. Convert to UIImage etc.

}
```

Comment: for this I need the video url. how to get the recent captured video url.... Thank you so very much for your response

Comment: If you need the video url, can just add this in the same block -         `NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[asset defaultRepresentation]url];`